# Haskell error: Couldn't match type 'a' with 'b'

Tags: haskell

i'm a newish to Haskell and have this piece of code:

```
import Control.Monad

data NestedList a = Elem a | List [NestedList a] deriving (Show)

instance Monad NestedList where
    return a = List [Elem a]
    (List (Elem a: xs)) >>= f = let a' = f a in a' `joinLists` xs

func :: a -> NestedList a
func a = List ([Elem a] ++ [Elem a])

joinLists :: NestedList a -> [NestedList a] -> NestedList a
joinLists (List a) b = List (a ++ b)

main = do let a = List [Elem 1, Elem 2] >>= func
          print a
```

What I am trying to do is to take a List with elements, replicate 1st element of the list and add a tail to this list. So List [Elem 1, Elem 2] would be equal to List [Elem 1, Elem 1, Elem 2]. I know that's not a good example of using Monads, but that's for the sake of learning.

I am getting an error like this:

```
Couldn't match type 'a' with 'b'
   'a' is a rigid type variable bound by
       the type signature for
          '>>= :: NestedList a -> (a -> NestedList b) -> NestedList b
   'b' is a rigid type variable bound by
       the type signature for
          '>>= :: NestedList a -> (a -> NestedList b) -> NestedList b
   Expected type: [NestedList b]
   Actual type: [NestedList a]
   In the second argument of 'joinLists', namely 'xs'
```

I understand the error is that it expects a different type variable of NestedList. What is the problem here?

Comment: your problem is using `joinLists`, `a'` is `Elem b` but `xs` is `[Elem a]`. The monad bind is `(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`

Comment: @josejuan a' is of type `NestedList a = List [Elem a]` and correct, `xs`  is `[Elem a] or [NestedList a]`. And joinLists takes NestedList a and [NestedList a], so it shouldn't cause a problem. How can I transform `[Elem a] to [Elem b]`?

Comment: @AidasSimkus `f` has type `(a -> m b)`, that is where that type variable `b` comes from.

Comment: @AidasSimkus `a'` is of type `Elem b`, because `f :: a -> NestedList b` for any `b`. Even if you only use it with `f :: a -> NestedList a`, `Monad` should work for functions even with `a` and `b` being different. It is up to you how to create `NestedList b` out of the remaining `NestedList a`. Perhaps, applying `f` to each element of `xs` would work, but that depends on the logic of what you are doing. Also, `joinLists` doesn't have a pattern for `Elem a`, so you are going to feel that soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your reference, here is a working monad instance of `NestedList`. It should not be very difficult to verify that this instance satisfies the monad laws.

```
import Control.Monad

data NestedList a = Elem a | List [NestedList a] deriving (Show)

instance Monad NestedList where
    return x = Elem x
    (Elem x)  >>= f = f x
    (List xs) >>= f = List $ map step xs
        where step (Elem a) = f a
              step lst = lst >>= f
```

---

Here is a test program:

```
import Control.Monad

data NestedList a = Elem a | List [NestedList a] deriving (Show)

instance Monad NestedList where
    return x = Elem x
    (Elem x)  >>= f = f x
    (List xs) >>= f = List $ map step xs
        where step (Elem a) = f a
              step lst = lst >>= f


double :: a -> NestedList a
double a = List ([Elem a] ++ [Elem a])


add :: (Num a) => a -> a -> NestedList a
add a e = Elem $ a + e


main = do let a = Elem 1 >>= double
          let b = List [Elem 1, Elem 2] >>= double
          let c = List [Elem 2,List [Elem 3,Elem 4],Elem 5] >>= add 1
          print a
          print b
          print c
```

And its output:

```
$ runhaskell t.hs 
List [Elem 1,Elem 1]
List [List [Elem 1,Elem 1],List [Elem 2,Elem 2]]
List [Elem 3,List [Elem 4,Elem 5],Elem 6]
```

Comment: Thank you! That's sort of what I was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 7):

> I know that's not a good example of using Monads, but that's for the sake of learning.

Specifically, your implementation of `>>=` is not general enough. What you have given has type:

> List a -> (a -> List a) -> List a

but Haskell insists on

> List a -> (a -> List b) -> List b

To me it looks like there is no good way to achieve what you want in a monad.

The deeper reason is that you want to modify the structure of the "container", rather than doing something with the "element" in a container specific way.